# Call super class method automatically

Tags: java, inheritance

Consider the following class

```
class A{
    public void init(){
        //do this first;
    }
    public void atEnd(){
        //do this after init of base class ends
    }
}

class B1 extends A{

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        super.init();
        //do new stuff.
        //I do not want to call atEnd() method here...
    }
}
```

I have several B1, B2,... Bn child classes which are already developed. All of them extend class A. If I want to add a new functionality in all of them, the best place to do so is define that in a method within class A. But the condition is that the method should always get called automatically just before the init() method of child class ends. 
One basic way to do so is to again add atEnd() method call at end of init() method of child classes. But is there any other way to do this smartly ??

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One way to do this is by making `init()` final and delegating its operation to a second, overridable, method:

```
abstract class A {
  public final void init() {
    // insert prologue here
    initImpl();
    // insert epilogue here
  }
  protected abstract void initImpl();
}

class B extends A {
  protected void initImpl() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Whenever anyone calls `init()`, the prologue and epilogue are executed automatically, and the derived classes don't have to do a thing.

Answer (score 4):

Another thought would be to weave in an aspect.  Add before and after advice to a pointcut.

Comment: If this is about protecting class invariants, AOP would be a very poor solution.

Comment: It's about "do stuff"; invariants aren't mentioned.  And I'm not sure that "very poor" is appropriate, based on the information supplied.

Answer (score 3):

Make `init()` `final`, and provide a separate method for people to override that `init()` calls in the middle:

```
class A{
    public final void init(){
        //do this first;
    }

    protected void initCore() { }

    public void atEnd(){
        //do this after init of base class ends
    }
}

class B1 extends A{

    @Override
    protected void initCore()
    {
        //do new stuff.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are reasonable workarounds but to address the exact question: no, there is no way to do this automatically. You must explicitly call `super.method()`.